# EF does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get objects from database based on a list of ids, but I get the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Here is my code

```
       shopingEntities db = new shopingEntities();
      var q = (from a in db.CatSetups
                     join b in db.CatofCats
                     on a.CatId equals b.ParentCatID
                     where a.CatId == 1

                     select new
                     {



               // ID        b.ChildCat




                     });

      ArrayList list = new ArrayList(q.ToList());
      var ok = (from cc in db.CatSetups
                where list.Contains(cc.CatId)
                select cc).ToList();
```

Comment: According to the current code, q is an empty anonymous type?

Comment: what property are you  selecting in your first query?

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you stop using `ArrayList`. Unless you are interfacing with libraries that are many years old there should be no need for it.  Even then, I would use `List` everywhere else and just copy to an `ArrayList` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well your problem, you are trying to find child categories for a given Category Id

```
var childCats=from a in db.CatSetups
               join b in db.CatofCats on a.CatId equals b.ParentCatID
               where a.CatId == 1
               select  b.ChildCat;//Assuming ChildCat is an integer

var cats=db.CatSetups.Where(c=>childCats.Contains(c.CatId)).ToList();
```

In case that `CatofCats` is the junction table in a many to many relationship and if you were using navigation properties:

```
public class CatofCats
{
    public int ParentCatID{get;set;}

    public int ChildCatID{get;set;}

    public virtual CatSetups ParentCat{get;set;}
    public virtual CatSetups ChildCat{get;set;}
}
```

Then your query would be:

```
var childCats=db.CatofCats.Where(c=>c.ParentCatID==1).Select(c=>ChildCat);
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much  octavioccl :) I am actually new to Linq. i thought array of ids like int [] ids would much lighter than var Ids.... Is using var list would be light as you use arrary of int for IDs

Answer (score 0):

There's simply no translation for `ArrayList.Contains`. But you don't need to do it this way. Just use:

```
var q = from a in db.CatSetups
        join b in db.CatofCats
        on a.CatId equals b.ParentCatID
        where a.CatId == 1
        select b.ChildCat;

var list = q.ToList();
```

Now if you use `Contains`, it resolves to [`Enumerable.Contains<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for which EF has a built-in translation path. Only if `T` is a primitive type though. That's why you shouldn't select an anonymous type.

Comment: Assuming that `b.ChildCat` is an integer. Maybe it should be something like `b.ChildCat.CatId` or `b.ChildCatId`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(q.ToList());
```

with

```
var list = q.ToList();
```

The [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) method from the non-generic `ArrayList` is not implemented in EF. [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) most definitely is.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that you are using `ArrayList` can't you just do:

`

```
var list = q.ToList()

var ok = (from cc in db.CatSetups
                where list.Contains(cc.CatId)
                select cc).ToList();
```

`

I'm not an EF expert but I suspect that contains only supports generic 
collections